# AngularJs multiselect dropdown list skip items on scroll up and down in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, html, css

First of all pardon me for my beginner level CSS skills.

I have an angular app where a multi select drop down list is used. This drop down list working fine as expected in IE but in chrome whenever there is scroll up or down, it skips items. e.g. if there are 5 items shown out of 20, on scroll down it will skip the item number 6 and will show the items from 7 till 11 and on next mouse scroll it will skip item number 12 and will display from 13 till 17.

Can please someone help me to fix this issue

```
<td class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
    <span style="width:100%; padding-left:10px;" class="pull-left">
         <select class="form-control  input-sm"
                    multiple multiselect-dropdown ng-model="selectedAddresses"
                    ng-change="AddressSelection()"
                    style="width:100%;">
             <option ng-repeat="item in ItemList" style="width:100% !important"
                        value="{{$index}}">
                    Address {{$index+1}}: {{item.Name}} - {{item.Location}}
             </option>
         </select>
     </span>
 </td>

.input-sm {
    min-width: 70px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I reproduced your code in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dUe1pZtWx6CiJrNV2wVb?p=preview) and it seems to work with Chrome

Comment: It is working fine but if you scroll down you will see item number 5 and 6 will be skipped and after first scroll it will start from item number 7. In IE it works find and after first scroll, it will bring the Item number 5 but not in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, but I reused your code and add some data to recreate this behavior, but it's working fine, items numbers are going well. Take a look at [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dUe1pZtWx6CiJrNV2wVb?p=preview) I did, maybe I did something differently, but I can't reproce the behavior you are describing :(

Comment: I have modified my question with your plunker output. First image is the default load and after first scroll, I am getting the output that is in the second picture. Here you can see it has skipped Address 5,6 and started displaying from Address 7. Although, Address 5,6 are there and I can get to them by clicking the up arrow button but not with mouse scroll?

Comment: And if you use the arrow up and down on the scrollbar, are you able to see items 5 and 6 ?

Comment: If so, then I think it's because you mousewheel scroll speed is too high. To resolve this you can reduce your mousewheel scroll speed or try to fake a slower scroll speed with some Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Jean. Reducing the mouse wheel speed has fixed it.